# CodeIgniter set image max-size to 0 and validate file type if jpg or png

Tags: php, codeigniter

Anyone can help me to set image max-size to 0.
Because I'm getting Error code: 1

Please help me to construct this code. I don't want to change the limit in `php.ini` Just want to know if there is a code solution for this problem:

```
function uploadPhoto()
{
    $control = 'filephoto';
    $path    = './upload/';
    $image   = $_FILES[$control]['name'];
    $size    = $_FILES[$control]['size'];

    if ($imageName = $this->doUpload($control, $path, $image, 'all')) {

    } else {

    }
}

function doUpload($control, $path, $imageName, $sizes)
{
    if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $u_id         = $session_data['u_id'];
        $alnum        = random_string('alnum', 16);
        if ( ! isset($_FILES[$control]) || ! is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$control]['tmp_name'])) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error_nofile', 'No file was chosen Error code: ' . $_FILES[$control]['error']);
            header('location:' . base_url() . "indexc/upload/");

            return false;
        }
        if ($_FILES[$control]['size'] > 2048000) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error_largefile', 'File is too large (' . round(($_FILES[$control]["size"] / 1000)) . 'kb), please choose a file under 2,048kb');
            header('location:' . base_url() . "indexc/upload/");

            return false;
        }
        if ($_FILES[$control]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error_failed', 'Upload failed. Error code: ' . $_FILES[$control]['error']);
            header('location:' . base_url() . "indexc/upload/");

            Return false;
        }
        switch (strtolower($_FILES[$control]['type'])) {
            case 'image/jpeg':
                $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES[$control]['tmp_name']);
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$control]["tmp_name"], $path . $imageName);
                break;
            case 'image/png':
                $image = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES[$control]['tmp_name']);
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$control]["tmp_name"], $path . $imageName);
                break;
            case 'image/gif':
                $image = imagecreatefromgif($_FILES[$control]['tmp_name']);
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$control]["tmp_name"], $path . $imageName);
                break;
            default:
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error_notallowed', 'This file type is not allowed');
                header('location:' . base_url() . "indexc/upload/");

                return false;
        }
        @unlink($_FILES[$control]['tmp_name']);
        $old_width  = imagesx($image);
        $old_height = imagesy($image);


        //Create tn version
        if ($sizes == 'tn' || $sizes == 'all') {
            $max_width  = 600;
            $max_height = 600;
            $scale      = min($max_width / $old_width, $max_height / $old_height);
            if ($old_width > 600 || $old_height > 600) {
                $new_width  = ceil($scale * $old_width);
                $new_height = ceil($scale * $old_height);
            } else {
                $new_width  = $old_width;
                $new_height = $old_height;
            }
            $new = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
            imagecopyresampled($new, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $old_width, $old_height);
            switch (strtolower($_FILES[$control]['type'])) {
                case 'image/jpeg':
                    imagejpeg($new, $path . '' . $u_id . '_' . $alnum . '_' . $imageName, 90);
                    break;
                case 'image/png':
                    imagealphablending($new, false);
                    imagecopyresampled($new, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $old_width, $old_height);
                    imagesavealpha($new, true);
                    imagepng($new, $path . '' . $u_id . '_' . $alnum . '_' . $imageName, 0);
                    break;
                case 'image/gif':
                    imagegif($new, $path . '' . $u_id . '_' . $alnum . '_' . $imageName);
                    break;
                default:
            }
        }

        imagedestroy($image);
        imagedestroy($new);
        /* print '<div style="font-family:arial;"><b>'.$imageName.'</b> Uploaded successfully. Size: '.round($_FILES[$control]['size']/1000).'kb</div>'; */

        $this->session->set_flashdata('success_upload', '<div style="font-family:arial;"><b>' . $imageName . '</b> Uploaded successfully. Size: ' . round($_FILES[$control]['size'] / 1000) . 'kb</div>');

        $postdata['p_u_id']           = $u_id;
        $postdata['p_content']        = $this->input->post('content');
        $postdata['p_image']          = $u_id . '_' . $alnum . '_' . $imageName;
        $postdata['p_image_original'] = $imageName;
        $postdata['p_posted']         = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        $res = $this->indexm->postinsert_to_db($postdata);

        header('location:' . base_url() . "indexc/upload/");
    } else {
        $this->load->view('index');
    }
}
```

I also want to validate if the file type is `jpg` or `png`

Please help me!

thanks,

joe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try default codeigniter library :

```
function do_upload()
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '100';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

            $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: but i want to resize the image width and height.

Comment: Reference  link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218247/codeigniter-image-resize