# Image resize not working in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

I am developing a web application. In my application, I am uploading an image to server and then resize it. I uploaded to server successfully. But when I resize image, it is not resizing image. But it is not throwing error as well.

This is my image file upload model

```
class file_helper extends CI_Model{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('image_lib');   
    }

    function generateRandomFileName()
    {
        $rand = rand(10000,99999);
        $file_name = time().$rand;
        return time().$rand;
    }

    function uploadImage()
    {
        $name = $this->generateRandomFileName();
        $config['upload_path']          = './'.UPLOAD_FOLDER.'/';
        $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['file_name'] = $name;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( !$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            $data['virtual_path'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER."/".$name.".".$data['file_ext'];
            return $data;
        }
    }


    function resizeImage($path)
    {
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = '/'.$path;
        $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['width']         = 300;
        $config['height']       = 50;

        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);

        if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize())
        {
            print_r($this->image_lib->display_errors());
        }
        else{
            echo "Ok";
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see in the model I print out "Ok" on success and print_r the error in failure. The path I passed is something like this "uploads/23344545.png". But that resize function always print out "Ok", but the image is not resized. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218247/codeigniter-image-resize

Comment: Thanks. It solved my problem.

Comment: Glad it helped you .. please mark this question as **closed**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter image resize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218247/codeigniter-image-resize)

Answer (score 0):

You need to resize the image while uploading

```
function uploadImage()
{
    $name = $this->generateRandomFileName();
    $config['upload_path'] = './'.UPLOAD_FOLDER.'/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['file_name'] = $name;
    $config['width'] = 300;
    $config['height'] = 50;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( !$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        $data = $this->upload->data();
        $data['virtual_path'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER."/".$name.".".$data['file_ext'];
        return $data;
    }
}
```