# Getting error while resizing image php codeigniter

Tags: php, image-resizing, codeigniter-3

I searched a lot but can't find out a solution for this problem actually I am trying to resize a image using codeigniter img_library. For resizing I am using this code. I am converting a base 64 encoded image using this code

```
$imgdata=base64_decode($image);
$imagename=$t.$s.'.'.$type;
$url= $target_dir.$imagename;
file_put_contents($url,$imgdata);         
$this->do_resize($url,$imagename);//calling the function to resize 



public function do_resize($url,$imagename){
   
    $source_path = $url;
    $target_path = base_url(). '/assets/test_images/'.$imagename;
    $config_manip = array(
        'image_library' => 'gd2',
        'source_image' => $source_path,
        'new_image' => $target_path,
        'maintain_ratio' => TRUE,
        'create_thumb' => TRUE,
        'thumb_marker' => '_thumb',
        'width' => 150,
        'height' => 150
    );
   
    $this->load->library('image_lib',$config_manip);
      $this->image_lib->initialize($config_manip);
     
      echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
    if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
    }
   
    $this->image_lib->clear();
}
```

and the error I am getting is this

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: imagecreatefrompng(): gd-png: fatal libpng error: [1E][36][BB][37]: invalid chunk type
>
> Filename: libraries/Image_lib.php
>
> Line Number: 1463
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: imagecreatefrompng(): gd-png error: setjmp returns error condition
>
> Filename: libraries/Image_lib.php
>
> Line Number: 1463
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: imagecreatefrompng(): 'C:/xampps/htdocs/yallaexab/assets/images/14747161693.jpg' is not a valid PNG file
>
> Filename: libraries/Image_lib.php
>
> Line Number: 1463

Comment: `imagecreatefrompng()`... It looks as though it is expecting a PNG file and you gave it a JPEG. Is jpeg image type allowed in the configuration? It normally works it out by looking at the file extension and the first few bytes of the image file.

Comment: i check the file type using  $f = finfo_open();
$mime_type = finfo_buffer($f, $imgdata, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); and its giving image/png so file is a valid png file.

Comment: i tried doing that also but still getting the same error..Message: imagecreatefrompng(): 'C:/xampps/htdocs/yallaexab/assets/images/1474723559188.png' is not a valid PNG file

Comment: i have check it and its showing there that's y i am saying its not a corrupted file..I think there is some mistake i have made in resize function which i am not able to find out.

Comment: maybe interesting? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218247/codeigniter-image-resize