# CodeIgniter image resize function not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, image-resizing

I made an image resize function in the CodeIgniter framework so users when users add an product to my database the image of the product gets resized to the width and height I want it to be.
For example I want all images to be displayed like 400 width and 400 height each picture.

This is my upload function in my controller file:

```
    public function upload(){

$this->load->library('upload');
$this->load->library('image_lib');

if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
    $error = array('error'=>$this->upload->display_errors());
    $this->load->view('product_form', $error);
}else{

    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = './upload/'.$file_data["file_name"];
    $config['new_image'] = './upload/'.$file_data["file_name"];
    $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
    $config['width']         = 400;
    $config['height']       = 400;

    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

    $this->image_lib->resize();


    $this->db->insert('products', array(
        'product_foto' => $file_data['file_name'],
        'product_naam'  => $this->input->post('product_naam'),
        'product_beschrijving' => $this->input->post('product_beschrijving'),
        'product_categorie'  => $this->input->post('product_categorie'),
        'ophaal_plaats'  => $this->input->post('ophaal_plaats'), 
        'date_created' => date('Y-m-d'),
        'date_updated' => date('Y-m-d')
        ));
    $data['img'] = base_url().'/upload/'.$file_data['file_name'];
    header('location:https://kadokado-ferran10.c9users.io/Product/');
}
```

This is my form in my view file:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('Product/upload'); ?>


        <table class="aanbieding-cadeau">

         <tr>
          <td><?php echo form_input(array('id'=>'product_naam', 'name'=>'product_naam', 'placeholder' => '1. Naam van het cadeau', 'size'=>25));?></td>
        </tr>

         <tr>
          <td><?php echo($selectField);?></td>
        </tr> 

         <tr>
          <td><?php echo form_input(array('id'=>'ophaal_plaats', 'name'=>'ophaal_plaats', 'placeholder' => '3.Kies een stad', 'size'=>25));?></td>
        </tr>

        <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Gebruik adres van mijn account</label>
        </div>

        <tr>
        <td>
            <h4>Upload foto</h4>
        <input type="file" name="userfile" />
          </td>
        </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><?php echo form_textarea(array('type'=>'textarea','id'=>'product_beschrijving', 'name'=>'product_beschrijving', 'placeholder' => '5. Vertel iets over dit cadeau..', 'size'=>25));?></td>
    </tr>


<tr>
<td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Cadeau aanbieden!" /></td>
</tr>
     </table>
    </form>
```

When I submit the form nothing gets added to my database anymore and no product is displayed since I added the resize function.

Comment: Have you  uploaded the image successfully??

Comment: gd2 library is installed properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make picture resize function when uploading in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45031063/how-can-i-make-picture-resize-function-when-uploading-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
public function upload(){

$this->load->library('upload');
$this->load->library('image_lib');

        $config['upload_path'] = './upload/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|bmp|jpeg';
        $config['max_size']    = '0';
        $config['max_width']  = '0';
        $config['max_height']  = '0';
        $config['encrypt_name']= true;
        $this->upload->initialize($config);


if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
    $error = array('error'=>$this->upload->display_errors());
    $this->load->view('product_form', $error);
}else{

    $data = $this->upload->data();
    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = './upload/'.$data["raw_name"].$data['file_ext'];
    $config['new_image'] = './upload/'.$data["raw_name"].$data['file_ext'];
    $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
    $config['width']         = 400;
    $config['height']       = 400;

    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

    $this->image_lib->resize();


    $this->db->insert('products', array(
        'product_foto' => $data["raw_name"].$data['file_ext'],
        'product_naam'  => $this->input->post('product_naam'),
        'product_beschrijving' => $this->input->post('product_beschrijving'),
        'product_categorie'  => $this->input->post('product_categorie'),
        'ophaal_plaats'  => $this->input->post('ophaal_plaats'), 
        'date_created' => date('Y-m-d'),
        'date_updated' => date('Y-m-d')
        ));
    $data['img'] = base_url().'/upload/'.$data["raw_name"].$data['file_ext'];
    header('location:https://kadokado-ferran10.c9users.io/Product/');
}
```

or refer to this answer : 
[How can I make picture resize function when uploading in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45031063/how-can-i-make-picture-resize-function-when-uploading-in-codeigniter/45033065#45033065)