# How to resize image on codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, model, controller, image-uploading, image-resizing

I get a module like a blog, and I must upload an image to my website. but when I upload my image not be resized/cropped automatically.

**CONTROLLER**

```
 function simpan_campaign(){
        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/images/upload'; //path folder
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|bmp'; //type yang dapat diakses bisa anda sesuaikan
        $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE; //Enkripsi nama yang terupload

        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        if(!empty($_FILES['filefoto']['name'])){

            if ($this->upload->do_upload('filefoto')){
                $gbr = $this->upload->data();
                //Compress Image
                $config['image_library']='gd2';
                $config['source_image']='./assets/images/upload'.$gbr['file_name'];
                $config['create_thumb']= FALSE;
                $config['maintain_ratio']= FALSE;
                $config['quality']= '50%';
                $config['width']= 380;
                $config['height']= 264;
                $config['new_image']= './assets/images/upload'.$gbr['file_name'];
                $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
                $this->image_lib->clear();
                $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
                $this->image_lib->resize();

                $image=$gbr['file_name'];
                $title=$this->input->post('title');
                $cashtarget=$this->input->post('cashtarget');
                $campcode=$this->input->post('campcode');
                $datefrom=$this->input->post('datefrom');
                $dateend=$this->input->post('dateend');
                $category=$this->input->post('category');
                $desc=$this->input->post('description');

                $this->main_model->save_campaign($title,$desc,$image,$cashtarget,$campcode,$datefrom,$dateend,$category);
                echo "Image berhasil diupload";
                redirect('account/add');
            }

        }else{
            echo "Image yang diupload kosong";
        }

    }
```

and my model like :

**MODEL**

```
    function save_campaign
($title,$desc,$image,$cashtarget,$campcode,$datefrom,$dateend,$category){
            $hsl=$this->db->query("INSERT INTO tcampaign (title,description,pathimage,cashtarget,campcode,datefrom,dateend,category) VALUES ('$title','$desc','$image','$cashtarget','$campcode','$datefrom','$dateend','$category')");
            return $hsl;
        }
```

I can upload but i cant resize or crop on my view

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218247/codeigniter-image-resize - look here.

Comment: i have to try, but fail

Comment: What resize errors do you get `echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();`

Comment: is the image even getting uploaded? you have no `display_errors()` logic for either the upload function or the resize function. adding elses, and these functions will 100% allow you to see what error is occuring...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the biggest problem was this declaration:

`'./assets/images/upload'.$gbr['file_name'];` if you notice there is no ending slash before the filename...

Also you used the same variable `$config` for both upload and resizing. This can also cause some unexpected results. Just use a different variable for both. Here we have `$upconfig` and `$config`.

I've also cleaned up the function a bit and added in the error methods so you can see what is going wrong if something does. You should handle the errors more elegantly than just echoing them.

```
function simpan_campaign() {
        $this->load->library('upload'); // not sure if you already autoloaded this
        // this way $config won't overwrite or add on to the upload config
        $upconfig['upload_path'] = './assets/images/upload/'; // missing end slash
        $upconfig['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|bmp';
        $upconfig['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
        $this->upload->initialize($upconfig);
        if (!empty($_FILES['filefoto']['name'])) {
            if ($this->upload->do_upload('filefoto')) {
                $filename = $this->upload->data('file_name');
                //Compress Image
                $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                $config['source_image'] = $this->upload->data('full_path'); // missing slash before name
                $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
                $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
                $config['quality'] = '50%';
                $config['width'] = 380;
                $config['height'] = 264;
                // not required as you have declared the same filename
                // the original image will be targeted for resize
                //$config['new_image'] = './assets/images/upload/' . $filename;
                $this->load->library('image_lib');
                $this->image_lib->clear();
                $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
                if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
                    echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
                    exit;
                }
                $title = $this->input->post('title');
                $cashtarget = $this->input->post('cashtarget');
                $campcode = $this->input->post('campcode');
                $datefrom = $this->input->post('datefrom');
                $dateend = $this->input->post('dateend');
                $category = $this->input->post('category');
                $desc = $this->input->post('description');

                $this->main_model->save_campaign($title, $desc, $filename, $cashtarget, $campcode, $datefrom, $dateend, $category);
                echo "Image berhasil diupload";
                redirect('account/add');
            } else {
                echo $this->upload->display_errors();
                exit;
            }
        } else {
            echo "Image yang diupload kosong";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Work for me on codeigniter 3, but i cant resize on codeigniter 2. i like codeigniter bcs i thing codeigniter 2 stable better than codeigniter 3 . Thx alex