# Codeigniter create thumb image by custom dimensions, how?

Tags: codeigniter

I have Codeigniter custom system, need upload image standard dimensions + create _thumb into same folder without duplicate. This is working code without thumb image creator... Can you help me?

```
    public function image($var, $id) {
    $config['upload_path'] = './cdn/' . $this->module;
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|webp';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('featured_image')) {
        
    } else {
        $data = $this->upload->data();
        if ($data['file_name'])
            $this->{$this->model}->featured_image = $data['file_name'];
    }
    return true;
}

public function image_upload() {
    $config['upload_path'] = './cdn/' . $this->module;
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $errors = 0;
    $error_message = '';
    $passed_files = [];
    $var = 'file';
    $files = $this->reArrayFiles(@$_FILES[$var]);
    foreach ($files as $idx => $file) {
        $_FILES[$var] = $files[$idx];
        if ($this->upload->do_upload($var)) {
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            if ($data['file_name']) {
                $ext = pathinfo($data['file_name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                $file_name = "IRecipes_" . str_replace([".", " "], "", microtime()) . rand(0, 100) . "_orig." . $ext;
                rename($data["full_path"], $data["file_path"] . $file_name);
                $passed_files[] = $file_name;
            }
        } else {
            $errors++;
            $error_message .= strip_tags($this->upload->display_errors());
        }
    }
    if ($passed_files && count($passed_files))
        $this->uploadFile[$var] = ($passed_files);

    if ($errors == count($files))
        die(json_encode(["error" => true, "message" => $error_message]));
    else
        die(json_encode(["error" => false, "files" => $passed_files]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to install **`ImageMagick`** on the `server/localhost`.

You can also check [**this**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.thumbnailimage.php) link for a working example on how to create the thumbnail.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CodeIgniter`'s built-in `image_lib` library which supports all three major image libraries: `GD/GD2, NetPBM, and ImageMagick`

[**Here**](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/image_lib.html) is official documentation and [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218247/codeigniter-image-resize) is a similar question addressing your issue. Hope this helps you.